# Kissing Thumbs On Hearing Name Of Prophet Mohammad

Tags: islamic-basis

I have been seeing this since my birth; people use to kiss their thumbs and put them over their eyes when they hear the name of our prophet Mohammad (peace be upon him).

Is it allowed in Islam or Shirk or Haram?

Comment: Truth claims are opinion based [Is there any way to make Truth questions constructive?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/is-there-any-way-to-make-truth-questions-constructive)

Answer (score 3):

Kissing the thumbs during adhan, if viewed as sunnah without a basis or sound ahadith (with a chain) would be classified as a bid'ah.

A person can kiss this thumbs, rub his eyes, place his hands on his head or any other permissible action, the condition being that he does not view this action as an act of ibadah, rather as a remedy, just as one taking eyedrops doesn't view this act as ibadah.

Allah knows best

Comment: just because the Hadith couldn't manage to be sound, does it make it Bid'ah?

Comment: I think you have to define bid'ah by drawing a line somewhere - and partaking in an action which is unsubstantiated (by way of hadith) is that line. It is also much more productive to undertake means of ibadah which are from sound sources.

Comment: OK. I'm sorry, I did not fully understand your answer. Can you plz tell me more about "rather as a remedy", so is/could kissing thumbs considered as "remedy"?

Comment: No need to apologise and I'm not aware of it being so. I tried using the eyedrops as an example

Comment: From what I know is that after prophet Muhammad (PBUH) died, once one of prophet was crying a lot by remembering prophet and asked Allah to show a glimpse of him, so according to the story, allah showed him in the thumbs and he kissed those thumbs. But Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

Its an innovative move also called Bidah. If u really respect Prophet Mohammad Sallalla hi Alaiyhi wassallam then this or recite darood on Muhammad (SAW).its Hadith Bukhari see it for urself .As innovation in Islam is srictly Prohibidden

Answer (score -2):

Its not biddah once the prophet saw allah aszawadjal and on that moment he kissed his thumbs and since then were sahabis doing that if they hear the name of our prophet salalahoe alaihi wasalam

Comment: "once the prophet saw allah aszawadjal and on that moment he kissed his thumbs" **reference** for this plz.... Even I've heard this from people.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE. We expect answers here to be substantive and referenced by Islamic scriptures. Please to through the help center especially the guideline, [How do I write good answers?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)